# how to load pages with ajax

Tags: ajax, loading

When I click my links to load the new page in the designated div with ajax the jquery effect on the div fires off and displatys the same information. i have external .html files made and the java script is set up to load all pages in the #content div.

> ```
> <ul id="navigationMenu">
>     <li>
>       <a class="home" href="index.html">
>             <span>Home</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
>
>     <li>
>       <a class="about" href="about.html">
>             <span>About</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
>
>     <li>
>        <a class="services" href="services.html">
>             <span>Services</span>
>          </a>
>     </li>
>
>     <li>
>       <a class="portfolio" href="portfolio.html">
>             <span>Portfolio</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
>
>     <li>
>       <a class="contact" href="contact.html">
>             <span>Contact us</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
> </ul>
>
> </div>
>
>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>
>   var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
>   var href = $('#navigationMenu li a').each(function(){
>       var href = $(this).attr('href');
>       if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
>           var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
>           $('#content').load(toLoad)
>       }                                           
>   });
>
>   $('#navigationMenu li a').click(function(){
>
>       var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
>       $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
>       $('#load').remove();
>       $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
>       $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
>       window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
>
>       $(function () {
>     $("li", "#navigationMenu").click(function (event) {
>         var url = $(this).attr("href"),
>             hash = url.replace(".html", ""),
>             content = $("#content");
>
>         content.html("<p>Loading...</p>");
>
>         $.ajax({
>             url : url,
>             dataType : "html",
>             success : function(data){
>                 content.find("p").fadeout(function(){
>                     content.find("p").html(data);
>                     window.location.hash = hash;
>                 });
>             }
>         })
>         event.preventDefault();
>     });
> });
>
>
>       function loadContent() {
>           $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
>       }
>       function showNewContent() {
>           $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
>       }
>
>       function hideLoader() {
>           $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
>       }
>       return false;
>
>
>
>   });
>
> });
> ```

Comment: My friend do you want to load the different page inside the div of existing page using ajax

Comment: i want each one of the links to display different text inside of the #content div.

Comment: then u can pass the url of the page to the function like function do_the_click(brl)
 {
 alert(brl);
 var request  =  $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: brl, 
        contentType: "text/html",
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "html",                
       
    });
     
     
     request.done(function( msg ) {
     document.getElementById('contentarea').innerHTML = msg;
     });
 
     request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
       alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
     });
 
 }

Comment: i appreciate your help.. would you mind reflecting that in the code i have posted so i can have a better understanding.

Comment: I have added an good example to do that u can try. if you stuck in any thing then i will definately help you and please upvote my answer so it will be helpful for others

Comment: please look at the script in my post. i want to understand what to add and change. i added the document. ready function then linked the class and the div content. but when the link is clicked it open the whole document instead of grabbing the data.

Comment: please share your code of link with me i have seen your function

Comment: code of link??? you mean the navigation links?

Comment: yes my friend code of <li> tags

Comment: i have added the links back in the main post.

Comment: i also added the java script you offered. and it does not accomplish my goal. maybe I am adding it wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the answer to load the data all in one page in the same div, then hide it, then display it as the links are clicked in nav.

> ```
> <!-- The navigation css is in styles.css -->
>
> <div id="main">
>
> <ul id="navigationMenu">
>     <li>
>       <a class="home" href="#home">
>             <span>Home</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
>
>     <li>
>       <a class="about" href="#about">
>             <span>About</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
>
>     <li>
>        <a class="services" href="#services">
>             <span>Services</span>
>          </a>
>     </li>
>
>     <li>
>       <a class="portfolio" href="#portfolio">
>             <span>Portfolio</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
>
>     <li>
>       <a class="contact" href="#contact">
>             <span>Contact us</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
> </ul>
>
> </div>
>
> <!-- The wrapper and the content div control the jquery slide up effect -->
> <div id="wrapper">
>   <div id="content">
>     <!-- The 5 pages content divs will display in this area -->   
>     <!-- The actual content I want to switch in and out of the panel, this is hidden -->
>
>  <div id="home" class="pages">
>  <h1 style=color:#7fff00;>Welcome</h1>
>  <p>hey this is cool</p>
>  </div>
>
>  <div id="about" class="pages">
>  <h1 style=color:#6495ed;>My Qualifications</h1>
>  <p>2 Whole bunch of text 2</div>
>
>  <div id="services" class="pages">
>  <h1 style=color:#ee7621;>Welcome</h1>
>  <p>3 Whole bunch of text 3</div>
>
>  <div id="portfolio" class="pages">
>  <h1 style=color:#ffb90f;>Welcome</h1>
>  <p>4 Whole bunch of text 4</div>
>
>  <div id="contact" class="pages">
>  <h1 style=color:#ff1493;>Welcome</h1>
>  <p>5 Whole bunch of text 5</div>     
>
>   </div>
> </div> 
>
>
>
> <!-- This is the slide show -->
> <div id="container">
>       <div id="examples">
>           <ul id="example1">
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide0.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide1.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide2.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide3.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide4.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>           </ul>
>
>   <script type="text/javascript">
>   $("#example1").zAccordion({
>   timeout: 4000,
>   slideWidth: 600,
>   width: 960,
>   height: 270
>   });
>   </script>
>
> </div>
> </div>
>
> <div id="foot">
> <a href="#top"><img src="img/upArrow.png" width="100" /></a>
> </div>
> </body>
> </html>
>
>
>
> $(document).ready(function () {
>     $(".pages").hide();
>     $("#navigationMenu a").click(function (e) {
>         e.preventDefault();
>         var item = this.href.split("#")[1];
>         $(".pages:visible").slideUp(function () {
>             $("#" + item).slideDown();
>         });
>     });
>     $("#home").show();
> });
>
> .pages{
> display: none}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function do_the_click(brl)
    {
    alert(brl);

    var url = eval("brl");
    $( "#content" ).load(url, function() {
        alert( "Load was performed." );
});
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="navigationMenu">
    <li>
      <a class="home" href="#" onclick="do_the_click('index.html');">
            <span>Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>


</ul>

<div class="abc" id = "content">
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

and please create folder with name js which contains the jquery library in parallel of this sample.html and create one sample index.html in parallel of it, hope this works for you

Comment: so your saying all of my javascript is useless?

Comment: I meant how would i add that to my existing javascript

Comment: @Nicho No you can use only this, it will do that whole process u can comment your javascript it is very simple code to do that what you are trying to do and please call thic function on click on <li> tags

Comment: I am not understanding you example... I have managed to add a function that does what I need it too. except when it loads the external html page it loads it to the full browser window instead of the target

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
     
  $('.about.').click(function(){
        $('#content').load(url + ' about.html');
     });
 
 })

Comment: @Nicho please also post the content of div on which you have a applied onclick event

Comment: @Nicho, I have edited my answer please try it now, i have only added the code to load different page in the your current page and extra fadein and fadeout functionality u can add

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can use:

```
$(function () {
    $("a", "#navigationMenu").click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).attr("href"),
            hash = url.replace(".html", ""),
            content = $("#content");

        content.html("<p>Loading...</p>");

        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            dataType : "html",
            success : function(data){
                content.find("p").fadeout(function(){
                    content.html(data);
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                });
            }
        })
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! your answer works. But instead of loading the page it just says loading... what do i need to change or add to get the about.html services.html and the contact.html to load?

Comment: oh snap! there was a minor error. Well, I have updated my code. Please use the new one. Good luck!

Comment: Also, you should not merge it with your ow code, just use this one. And this will work. The code I have given is complete.

Comment: The code I have posted has been simplified. It works it's minimal and it's separated by HTML CSS and js.

Comment: I just want you to use the above code in terms of javascript. your CSS and HTML are fine.

Comment: What is wrong with the solution I posted? And your changing my function to a fade out function

Comment: you are using content.find("p").html(data); and it should be content.html(data); also, there is no harm in trying my code, just for one time.